# Xcode 12.5, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64 problem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build an IOS project on Xcode 12.5.
There is no problem when the real device is connected or when I try to build with the simulator. But I get this error when Any IOS Device is selected. Any IOS Device is selected to archive my project and I get an error message while archiving.
I have changed the'Build Active Arch. Only' and 'Excluded Architecture' settings many times, but the problem has not been resolved.

[image: error image]

please help me with this problem..

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856596/failed-to-tns-build-ios-due-as-mdfinternationalization-and-materialcomponents-di

Comment: However, the problem is with material components. Try to replace MDFInternationalization.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved when I changed it to IOS Deployment Target 12.0

- Build Active Architecture Only selected as yes.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried many solutions and this was the only one that worked. Have been using Firebase Package Manager  installed on M1 and unable to build for device until I upped the deployment target.   Note you should change the deployment target both on Project Info and Target General.

Comment: What if I want to develop application for at least iOS 15 devices?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this screenshot -
[image]

The issue is `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7`.

Can you go to `Build Settings` of your

1. project
2. app target
3. all of the pod targets if you use pods

search for `armv7` and delete it if it exists?

After this, do a `Product > Clean Build Folder` & now try running/building the app.

Comment: thank you Tarun for your answer but that didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case i use this solution and it's worked for me.

Add this given below code into your podfile at the bottom and run "**pod install**" command. And Good to go.

At this point **'12.0'** You can change accordingly. Based upon your project. For **exmp**: '11.0' or '10.0' like this. It should be match with the **platform: ios, '12.0'** this line in your podfile at the Second position.

**In my case**

Exmp: **platform: ios, '12.0'** so **config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'**. So 12.0 matched in both.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    # some older pods don't support some architectures, anything over iOS 11 resolves that
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my project. I use **Xcode 13.3.1**.
So I updated my **Podfile** with next way(was added excluded arch and deployment target):

```
$iOSVersion = '13.1'
platform :ios, $iOSVersion
use_frameworks!

def general_pods
  pod 'Some_pods_here'
end

target 'Some_target1' do
  general_pods
  pod 'Some_pod_here'
end

target 'Some_target2' do
  general_pods
  pod 'some_pod_here'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=*]"] = "armv7"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $iOSVersion
    end
  end

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if Gem::Version.new($iOSVersion) > Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $iOSVersion
    end
   end
 end
end
```